# image too small on iPad

Tags: html, image, ipad, image-size

I use a iPad from school and i have to make this site to work on a iPad only.
I have a image of 1024x768 but when i display it it is a lot smaller.

[image: wrong size]

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="resources/data/pattern_02.png">
</div>
```

the css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    /*min-height: max-device-height;*/
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

give that a try as well, if it isn't too late!